# SQL Join Table Date search

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to add a search by date form for a SQL query. The original query without the WHERE was working fine so I know I am just not correctly passing in the dates to the query. When I search return nothing. Here is what I have:

```
$start = $_POST['start'];
    $end = $_POST['end'];

    $search_start = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('-', '/', $start)));


    $search_end = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('-', '/', $end)));

    //exports 2016-04-01 2016-04-06

    // Get Report
    $query = "SELECT wp_ch_ifs_neworders.order_contact_id, wp_ch_ifs_neworders.order_date, wp_ch_ifs_neworders.order_contact, wp_ch_ifs_neworders.order_first_name, wp_ch_ifs_neworders.order_last_name, wp_ch_ifs_contacts.contact_email, wp_ch_ifs_contacts.contact_phone, wp_ch_ifs_neworders.order_address, wp_ch_ifs_neworders.order_city, wp_ch_ifs_neworders.order_state, wp_ch_ifs_neworders.order_zip
     FROM wp_ch_ifs_contacts
     INNER JOIN wp_ch_ifs_neworders
     ON wp_ch_ifs_contacts.contact_id=wp_ch_ifs_neworders.order_contact_id
     WHERE wp_ch_ifs_neworders.order_date BETWEEN %d AND %s, $search_start, $search_end 
     ORDER BY wp_ch_ifs_neworders.order_date DESC;";
```

Both the date in the table and the search date display like this `2016-04-01` so I feel like it should work fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dates need to be in quotes in a SQL query. And there's absolutely no reason for `%d` and `%s` in the query, those are format operators used with `sprintf`.

```
$query = "SELECT wp_ch_ifs_neworders.order_contact_id, wp_ch_ifs_neworders.order_date, wp_ch_ifs_neworders.order_contact, wp_ch_ifs_neworders.order_first_name, wp_ch_ifs_neworders.order_last_name, wp_ch_ifs_contacts.contact_email, wp_ch_ifs_contacts.contact_phone, wp_ch_ifs_neworders.order_address, wp_ch_ifs_neworders.order_city, wp_ch_ifs_neworders.order_state, wp_ch_ifs_neworders.order_zip
 FROM wp_ch_ifs_contacts
 INNER JOIN wp_ch_ifs_neworders
 ON wp_ch_ifs_contacts.contact_id=wp_ch_ifs_neworders.order_contact_id
 WHERE wp_ch_ifs_neworders.order_date BETWEEN '$search_start' AND  '$search_end' 
 ORDER BY wp_ch_ifs_neworders.order_date DESC;";
```

Comment: Thats what I was thinking. I was altering code from the companies past developer and not a SQL master. I will try this